# Parsing custom string gives wrong date

Tags: iphone, ios, nsstring, nsdateformatter

I have a string that has a date format of `HH:mm` so for example it could `12:00` or `22:00`, and I input that into my `NSDateFormatter` by setting it as the date format. I just need to construct a custom date. The problem is when I have done this and I get my parsed string as `2012-05-17 12:00:00 +0000` if the date is the 17th of May.

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *output = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[output setDateFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"yyyy-MM-d %@:00 +0000",@"12:00"]];
NSString *finalTodayString = [output stringFromDate:today];
parsedDateString = [NSString stringWithString:finalTodayString];
```

The problem is when I parse it again to just include the `HH:mm` I get something totally different. For example if I have this code.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-d HH:mm ZZZ"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:fullDateString];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormmater2 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormmater2 setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];
NSString *string =[dateFormmater2 stringFromDate:date];
```

Then the `string` **should** be `12:00` but instead it becomes `14:00`. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the Greenwich Meridian time "+0000" from the first code

Comment: I found the solution, I just needed to add `ZZZ` instead of `+0000` in my first code. Thanks for the solution.